# An App ID with Identifier is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, identifier

I was working on app in the development phase, I used my personal developer account to build the app so I can test it on the real device.

No when I have the client's account and I need to create the app id on it it giving me this error :

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.myTeamName.myAppName' is not available. Please enter a different string.

I didn't create any app ids in my personal account

I've tried deleting all provisioning profiles I have but still not working.

Comment: It sounds like that bundle id has been associated with your personal account.  This would have been done automatically as soon as you built the app for installation on your device.  Check for an "XC .." identifier in the certificates, identifiers and profiles section of developer.apple.com

Comment: Should I delete this XC certificate?

Comment: If you want the bundle id to be available to another developer program membership then you need to remove all references to it from your membership.

Comment: I've deleted the XC certificate but still have same issue

Comment: You may well have to pick a new bundle id. Once it has been associated with one account it can be very difficult to move it.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same problem. I entered a BundleID in the format  com.icloud.appleID.AppName  and got the same message that it is not available.  I tried multiple variations of the AppName and got the same error message.

I then tried entering a Bundle ID in the format AB123456C7.com.icloud.appleID.AppName where the AB123456C7 is the developer's Team ID, and IT WORKED.  It would have been great if the error messages had correctly indicated that it was a formatting issue and not the misleading not-available issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once a bundle ID is taken, there's no way to make it available again. Deleting certificates / provisioning profiles does not affect the bundle ID in any way.

Simply use a new bundle ID in the Apple Developer Portal.